# Max in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I am trying to use this in my query:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2014 THEN  remark ELSE '-' END)
```

Table sample:

```
 EmpID  Year   Remark 
 1      2016   Normal
 1      2014   Good
 1      2015   Very Good 
 1      2016   Good
 1      2010   Poor
 1      2016   Well
```

Report I am getting:

```
EmpID   2010    2014   2015        2016
1       Poor    Good   Very Good   Normal
```

Report I actually want:

```
EmpID   2010    2014    2015         2016
1       Poor    Good    Very Good    Normal - Good - Well
```

When I call query I am getting only one row but I want to concatenate all row for respective year.

How to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want year columns to be dynamic or static?

Comment: I am already getting this dynamically  using distinct year query but thats not problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is nothing to do with the MAX because you can use pivoting + STUFF with FOR XML PATH:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.EmpID, 
            t.[Year],
            STUFF((
            SELECT '-'+Remark
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE t.EmpID = EmpID AND t.[Year] = [Year]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') Remark
    FROM YourTable t
) as d
PIVOT (
    MAX(Remark) FOR [Year] IN ([2010],[2014],[2015],[2016])
) as pvt
```

In `d` part you get:

```
EmpID   Year    Remark
1       2010    Poor
1       2014    Good
1       2015    Very Good
1       2016    Normal-Good-Well
```

- `STUFF` is used to remove first `-`,
- `FOR XML PATH` used to make values from the rows as 1 row,
- `PIVOT` to convert rows to columns

Output:

```
EmpID   2010    2014    2015        2016
1       Poor    Good    Very Good   Normal-Good-Well
```

**EDIT#1**

Another way with MAX and CASE WHEN (same output):

```
SELECT  EmpID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2010 THEN Remark END) as [2010],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2014 THEN Remark END) as [2014],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2015 THEN Remark END) as [2015],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2016 THEN Remark END) as [2016]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.EmpID, 
            t.[Year],
            STUFF((
            SELECT '-'+Remark
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE t.EmpID = EmpID AND t.[Year] = [Year]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') Remark
    FROM YourTable t
) as d
GROUP BY EmpID
```

**EDIT#2**

Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @col nvarchar(max)

SELECT @col = (
    SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME([Year])
    FROM YourTable
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.EmpID, 
            t.[Year],
            STUFF((
            SELECT ''-''+Remark
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE t.EmpID = EmpID AND t.[Year] = [Year]
            FOR XML PATH('''')
            ),1,1,'''') Remark
    FROM YourTable t
) as d
PIVOT (
    MAX(Remark) FOR [Year] IN ('+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Best answer, because this explains use of `STUFF`, `XML`  and `PIVOT`

Comment: it works for me but one more thing  if i want  attach more than one column in Remark section like attach  suppose  remark+" "+Grade - remark+" "+Grade is it possible

Comment: Hi I need help is it possible to get year dynamic inside select statement and how?

Comment: But you have written *I am already getting this dynamically using distinct year query*...

Comment: yes using C# query but I felt any other way  if it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124979/discussion-between-pravin-and-gofr1).

Answer (score 1):

You can query like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  empid, year,
  STUFF((SELECT ' - ' + remark FROM #table WHERE empid = t.empid AND year = t.year
  FOR xml PATH ('')), 1, 3, '') AS testRemark
FROM #table t
GROUP BY empid, year)
SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT (MAX(testRemark) FOR year IN ([2010], [2014], [2015], [2016])) p
```

Output:

```
empid   2010    2014    2015        2016
1       Poor    Good    Very Good   Normal - Good - Well
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Chars = STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [Char]
    FROM dbo.Chars
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
```

Above can be used to concatinate values into a single field. Incorporate this into your query using a group on Year.

source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can concatenate your string like that:

```
SELECT T.EmpID
    , T.[Year]
    , STUFF(T2.[Remark], 1, 3, '') AS Remark
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, [Year] FROM #Test) AS T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONCAT(' - ', T2.Remark)
    FROM #Test AS T2
    WHERE T2.EmpID = T.EmpID
        AND T2.[Year] = T.[Year]
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) AS T2(Remark);
```

Query above will output this:

```
╔═══════╦══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ EmpID ║ Year ║        Remark        ║
╠═══════╬══════╬══════════════════════╣
║     1 ║ 2010 ║ Poor                 ║
║     1 ║ 2014 ║ Good                 ║
║     1 ║ 2015 ║ Very Good            ║
║     1 ║ 2016 ║ Normal - Good - Well ║
╚═══════╩══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Now you just have to pivot it based on `EmpID` and `Year` values, which you already know how to do, based on your comments.